# Python - is there a way to check whether a dictionary contains a specific amount of key-value pairs?

Tags: python, dictionary, conditional-statements

I am a novice programmer, and I am wondering if there is a way to write a *conditional statement* to test whether a given dictionary contains more than x number of *key-value* pairs. Also, is there a way to return the number of *key-value* pairs a dictionary has in general?

My example dictionary I am using:

```
contact_list = {"jenna": 'jenna.smith@python.org', "bob": 'bob.smith@python.org', "lucy": 'lucy.hunters@python.org', "devin": 'devin.namachuk@python.org', "fiona": 'fiona.jevran@python.org'}
```

Any input on how to solve this using a *conditional statement* would be very helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `len()` which returns the number of elements in an object. This works on all iterables.

```
if len(contact_list)) > certain_count:
    pass
```

Len can also be used on a string for example. In that case it would return the number of characters the string contains.